# Alter Drupal views argument title substitutions

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

I have a views with Tid with depth argument. I'm using this argument in page title ("Videos from %1").
The substitutions is replaced by the term name ("Videos from PHP" for example). But I need it to be replaced by the range of terms with its parents, if it is child term ("Videos from Computers PHP"). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this method will get you on the right track. You will probably want to put this in a preprocess function in your template.php file.

[Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/6)